The answer may vary but only one is relevant!
I've removed the lines from the five large squares. Can you figure out how to put them back in order to create something relevant?



Here is the answer:

 

Why?

 Let’s look at the sequence above and trace out the shapes highlighted by the lines. Notice that they form the letters I,L,C,D.


These are all

 Letters of Roman numerals and on top of that they are in fact in order from smallest to largest!

The missing ones

 Are V,X,M


 So what are we to do with these to complete the puzzle? Well notice that the year 2025 is just around the corner and can be exclusively written with the missing numerals and only five of them: MMXXV…

So

 We just need to complete the image highlighting those letters of course and we have finished our puzzle!
 


Great job, you got it!
